# Suppress duplicates in GraphQL response

Tags: graphql

How can I merge any duplicate rows I receive in a request response?

I requested the last 200 books that have been viewed by the user and, in the results, I have duplicates.

The result looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "view_book": [
            {
                "views": 4,
                "book": {
                    "id": "26910093",
                    "title": "Book name 1",
                }
            },
            {
                "views": 7,
                "book": {
                    "id": "26910093",
                    "title": "Book name 1",
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

So, is it possible to suppress the duplication with GraphQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. I don't think there's anything in the GraphQL specs that solves your problem. However, I came across 2 interesting libraries that try to fix this issue by reducing the doubled nodes / normalising the response.

The technique is described here: [Reducing GraphQL response Medium](https://medium.com/@gajus/reducing-graphql-response-size-by-a-lot-ff5ba9dcb60)

The libs can be found here:

- https://github.com/gajus/graphql-deduplicator
- https://github.com/banterfm/graphql-crunch

Note: I didn't use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, unfortunately, is probably, but you shouldn't. GraphQL should remain an implementation on top of whatever your APIs are, and if your data is returning duplicates, GraphQL had better return it, too. If you've got duplicates, you should filter them in your business-logic layer before handing it back to your GraphQL resolvers.

Comment: but that will require changing the data model which is not feasible or even possible in some cases